# Object property access performance difference

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

#### Some context to my Question. Actual Question starts further below

I was curious about which way to store a list of References would be faster for accessing specific items later on.

To test the Performance i used [JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me) and created 2 Variables containing the same list of items with a key and a reference to the original element.

I created an object, where the property would be the key and the value would be the reference. And on the other hand i created an array containing Objects with a key property and a references property containing the reference.

I wanted to test which would be faster at accessing a specific item.

```js
const elementIDsObj = {
    "123": "123",
    "234": "123",
    "345": "123",
    "456": "123",
    "567": "123",
    "678": "123",
    "789": "123",
    "890": "123",
    "901": "123",
    "012": "123",
    "abc": "123"
};

const elementIDsArray = [
    {key: "123", ref: "123"},
    {key: "234", ref: "123"},
    {key: "345", ref: "123"},
    {key: "456", ref: "123"},
    {key: "567", ref: "123"},
    {key: "678", ref: "123"},
    {key: "789", ref: "123"},
    {key: "890", ref: "123"},
    {key: "901", ref: "123"},
    {key: "012", ref: "123"},
    {key: "abc", ref: "123"}
];
```

To access a specific item of the object-type i would just use `elementsIDsObj[KEY]`, and for the array-type i would have used the following code `elementIDsArray.find(item => item.key === KEY);`

I've made this comparison, as i didn't know how the direct access of object properties were implemented and i though it would be somewhat the same i've tried to recreate with the array-structure.

Turns out, its implemented differently as i thought and therefore the first access is way faster then the array-type iteration thingy i've tried.

#### Question

To get to the point of this Question, initially i tried this with keys as Strings only containing numbers and added at last a Key containing only letters.
I've got surprised that the direct access with a key containing at least one letter is way faster than keys only containing numbers.

And i would like to know, why is this the case. Whats the magic behind the access of Object properties, that causes this huge difference in access time.
[JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me/yal6g910g3/1)

##### The testing environment

**Browser**: Google Chrome - Version 103.0.5060.134
**OS**: MacOS Monterey - Version 12.3.1 (21E258)

|  | Key 'Alpha-Numeric' | Key 'Numeric-Only' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ops/s | 575,490,052.66 ± 4.68% | 47,066,784.33 ± 2.74% |

---

**Browser**: Mozilla Firefox - Version 80.0.1 (64-Bit)
**OS**: MacOS Monterey - Version 12.3.1 (21E258)

|  | Key 'Alpha-Numeric' | Key 'Numeric-Only' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ops/s | 1,139,482,575.49 ± 7.52% | 214,063,334.44 ± 3.2% |

---

**Browser**: Mozilla Firefox - Version 103.0.1 (64-Bit)
**OS**: MacOS Monterey - Version 12.3.1 (21E258)

|  | Key 'Alpha-Numeric' | Key 'Numeric-Only' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ops/s | 1,279,722,302.67 ± 0.91% | 1,210,963,390.96 ± 3.27% |

---

**Browser**: Google Chrome - Version 104.0.5112.69
**OS**: Android 11 - One Plus

|  | Key 'Alpha-Numeric' | Key 'Numeric-Only' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ops/s | 148,180,565.26 ± 0.6% | 7,392,240.71 ± 0.41% |

---

**Browser**: Mozilla Firefox - Version 103.1.0
**OS**: Android 11 - One Plus

|  | Key 'Alpha-Numeric' | Key 'Numeric-Only' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ops/s | 677,170,098.93 ± 0.42% | 681,474,092.7 ± 0.22% |

It seems, Firefox had changes on their JS Engine, that removed the huge difference.
Where as Chrome still has a different implementation that causes this huge difference.

Thank you in advance

Comment: [I can't reproduce that result](https://imgur.com/a/eTltkaf) so it is either being influenced by other factors on your system or is an implementation detail of your specific JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Hmmm . . . might be, i cant really test it on many different machines. Although i could test it on one other machine, that gave me the same results.

Comment: Running the jsbench produces a result within 1% consistently (on an iPad). Of course, the js engine in use might have different implementations that explain the difference. You might be able to validate that by getting someone to run the test on the same engine, if you say which it is

Comment: You are absolutely right. I've added the used browser and my operating system as information to the question at the section `Testing environment`.